# How to call Localization.string file content

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I get the key value from the Localization.string file on iPhone?

Comment: If you provided an example of the code you use, that would be helpful to point you in the right direction.

Comment: If your code is working as you start by stating - what are you really asking about then? Be precise and your questions will be answered quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSLocalizedString(@"Your_Localized_String_Name",@"");`

Comment: Pls provide some code and most importantly accept some answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your strings file "Localizable.strings" exactly if you want to use the easy default behaviour described there. Otherwise, you need to provide the name of the strings file.

In your case, the code would be more like:

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];

    NSString *locString = [thisBundle
        localizedStringForKey:assortedKeys[keyIndex++]
        value:@"No translation" table:@"Localization"];
```

If, and only if you rename Localization.string to Localization.strings